# Simulating oscillating loads on Ansys Workbench

Tags: mechanical-engineering, finite-element-method, simulation, ansys-workbench

I am working on a project to perform fatigue analysis and frequency analysis on a tandem bike that I modeled. How do I simulate the oscillating loads involved in pedalling?

Comment: What have you considered so far? Will you include effort from both legs? Like while one pushes down the other pulls up? As professionals do with cycling shoes or clips??